# Android telecom Connection private function (supportedAudioRoutes)

Tags: android, audio, call, audio-route, telecom

Why google dont provide this function for normal use (android.telecom.Connection)?

I need this function for disable bluetooth selection for my call. I think that in java we can use reflection for get this function, but im using Xamarin and its impossivel using reflection

```
/**
     * Sets the supported audio routes.
     *
     * @param supportedAudioRoutes the supported audio routes as a bitmask.
     *                             See {@link CallAudioState}
     * @hide
     */
    public final void setSupportedAudioRoutes(int supportedAudioRoutes) {
        if ((supportedAudioRoutes
                & (CallAudioState.ROUTE_EARPIECE | CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER)) == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "supported audio routes must include either speaker or earpiece");
        }

        if (mSupportedAudioRoutes != supportedAudioRoutes) {
            mSupportedAudioRoutes = supportedAudioRoutes;
            for (Listener l : mListeners) {
                l.onSupportedAudioRoutesChanged(this, mSupportedAudioRoutes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer ist simple and easy. You are not supposed to use it.

Please read the [specification](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/telecomm/java/android/telecom/Connection.java;l=71) and understand that **Represents** does not mean **Controls**.